# Probability for coin under glass with already chosen glass

Tags: probability

We have 3 glasses ,one contains coin under it .We randomly shuffled the glasses.What is probability of coin under that glass given u have already chosen a glass.

Comment: What do you think the probability is? Perhaps $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @MattiP. i think 1/3 will be in that case when need to choose the glass.Here we have already chosen a glass out of three,so we need to tell probability of coin under the glass.

Comment: @RahulKumar I don't see how that changes anything. Each glass has a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ that it has a coin under it. Whichever you choose, the probability is just that. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MattiP. sorry i am put my question properly .I would like rephrase it. Suppose we have three glass A,B,C and one contain a coin under it .If glass A is already chosen,what is probability coin under it. i thought its a conditional probability .where probability of chosing glass a is 1/3 and probability of coin under it is 1/2 so overall probability is 1/2*1/3=1/6.make me correct if i am wrong

Comment: I feel like we're getting into Monty Hall territory here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table of all the possible cases, I've abbreviated G=Glass:
 $$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & \text{Select G1} & \text{Select G2} & \text{Select G3} \\ \hline \text{Coin in G1} & \text{Win} &  &  \\ \hline \text{Coin in G2} &  & \text{Win} &  \\ \hline \text{Coin in G3} &  &  & \text{Win} \\ \hline  \end{array}
$$
As you see, there are a total of 9 combinations, **which are all equally likely**. Three of them are winning combinations, so the probability of a win in this case is $\frac{3}{9}= \frac{1}{3}$.

On the other hand, if you have already chosen a glass, then whichever you choose, the probability of a win is $\frac{1}{3}$ because there are three glasses and only one of them is a winner.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, after choosing a glass the probability of the coin to be found in the glass will be 1/2. As the sample space changes for the problem to (coin present, coin not present). If we consider the probability of choosing a glass then it would be 1/6 as the probability of choosing the glass is 1/3 and probability of the coin to be found in the glass is 1/2.

Comment: I would disagree with you. What are the probabilities for "coin present" and "coin not present"? I know that these are the two available options, but that doesn't make the probability equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, in the lottery you can either win or not win, but that doesn't mean that the probability of winning the lottery is $\frac{1}{2}$. Solution: you have to think about the probabilities of each case, not only count how many cases there are.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have 3 glasses A, B and C we would like to estimate the probability that we find the coin under the glass given that we have selected glass A.

$P(\text{coin in A} | \text{select glass A})$ = $\frac{P(\text{coin in A, select glass A})}{P(\text{select glass A})}$ = $\frac{1/9}{1/3}$ = $\frac{1}{3}$